# How come two different javascript events treat this function differently?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript-function:

```
  onMouseMoved = (function(_this) {
    console.log(_this)
    return function(event) {

      console.log(event)
      return;
    };
  })(this);
```

How come the mousemove-event trigers

If I add this listener:

```
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved, false);
```

`console.log(event)` get's triggered but not `console.log(_this)`

but if I add this listener:

```
  document.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseMoved, false);
```

It's the other way around, why?

Comment: Unlikely. Can you show the console output that you received?

Comment: `console.log(_this)` happens when the inner function is initially assigned to the onMouseMoved variable and at no other time.

Comment: The outer (IIFE) function represents something that javascript must execute in order to return and set a value for onMouseMoved.  Once that value is set, the outer function is not called again.  The value that the outer function returns is a reference to another, different function (the one that calls console.log(event)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not invoking `console.log(this)` in the event handler, you're invoking that *immediately*. It's an immediately-invoked function expression, or IIFE. It executes and returns a function which is assigned to `onMouseMoved`.

```
  onMouseMoved = (function(_this) {
    console.log(_this)
    return function(event) {

      console.log(event)
      return;
    };
  })(this);

  // console.log(_this) has already bee called at this point
  // onMouseMoved has been set to the returned function:
  //
  // function(event) {
  //   console.log(event)
  //   return;
  // };

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved, false);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

That `console.log(_this)` is only going to be called when `onMouseMoved` is instantiated the first time.

That `onMouseMove` is defined as a function which is called immediately with a value of `this` (probably for function scoping reasons). That console logging of `_this`, isn't inside its event handling function, so it wouldn't be called on the events.